# Program not storing values in an array

Tags: java

Was trying to make a sorting program of integers entered by user and wanted it to take as many integer user wants, without first asking how many int he wanna sort , but while taking input it just crashes , 
        **basically the problem is it is not storing values in array**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class apple {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int j = 0;
        int[] arr;
        arr = new int[j];
        while (true) {
            arr[j] = scan.nextInt();
            if (arr[j]==(int)'\n'){break;}
            j++;
            arr = new int[j];
        }
        for(j = 0 ;j <  arr.length ;j++){
            System.out.print(arr[j] + "    ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `if (arr[j]=='\n'){break;}` for an int???

Comment: And for an array of size 0. Your question is best answered by leaving the tutorial and getting a decent Java book since the solution is to learn the basics of the language.

Comment: if the index of an integer array equals a new line character... lol what.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ain't working even if i type if(arr[j]==(int)'\n'){break;}

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels also array size increases in loop checked with this 
 
 // arr[j] = scan.nextInt();
          //  if (arr[j]==(int)'\n'){break;}
            j++;
            arr = new int[j];
            System.out.println(arr.length);

Answer (score 2):

#### Arrays

First, use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` in conjunction with `Scanner.nextInt()`. Next, you are creating an array of size `0`; it can't store any values unless you first copy it<sup>**1**</sup> (because Java arrays are fixed length). You can use [`Arrays.copyOf(int[], int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) to do that. And, you can use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to display your array after you fill it. Something like,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int j = 0;
int[] arr = new int[j];
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    arr = Arrays.copyOf(arr, ++j);
    arr[j - 1] = scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

#### Collections

Java [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) (like [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)<sup>**2**</sup>) are more flexible, allowing a variable number of elements. Sadly they cannot operate directly with primitive types<sup>**3**</sup>, but can be used to store the corresponding [wrapper classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class). Something like,

```
List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    al.add(scan.nextInt()); // <-- int will be autoboxed to Integer
}
// int j = al.size(); // <-- like array.length, if you want to know how
// many numbers were read.
System.out.println(al); // ArrayList, unlike arrays, overrides toString
```

<sup>**1**<sub>Which has a cost.</sub></sup>
<sup>**2**<sub>A collection backed by an array.</sub></sup>
<sup>**3**<sub>Although primitive types can be [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).</sub></sup>

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is an appropriate technique to teach a beginner.  Nobody actually does it like this.

Comment: yeah cant understand code, i think need to learn it more deeply

Comment: @Elliott thanks for editing your post following my earlier comment.  I'd still like to note that the technique using the `ArrayList` is far superior to the technique using `Arrays.copyOf`.

Answer (score 1):

@Elliot Frisch explains how to do this with an array that you "grow" each time you want to add element by reallocating and copying the array.

A simpler idea is to replace the `int[] arr;` with

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then you can just use `list.add(scan.nextInt());` to add the integer to the list.  The `ArrayList` takes care of "growing" the storage behind the scenes.  (A `LinkedList` would work just as well here.)